# In Xcode 8.3 some swift class files are in red colour

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8

[image]

I haven't done anything. I just copied into another folder. When I run this code everything is working fine but don't know why some Swift class files are in red colour. Can someone please suggest me a solution?

Comment: path/file  is missing

Comment: Those red files references are missing, or you have just moved the files to some other location, Just add again those missing files.

Comment: "I just copied into another folder" means that the path of the files have been changed! try to right-click on the file and select "Show in Finder" option...

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226579/xcode-8-red-files-but-not-missing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613358/move-xcode-project-causes-red-textmissing-files-from-project

Comment: You could check the links I added in my second comment then, I hope they helped you...

Comment: Right Click on OnBoarding.. Click add Files option..  It will take you to your actual file location inside project folder. there you will find that these files , just add them.. Error will go

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. If you believe your question is not useful or is no longer useful, it should be *deleted* instead of editing out all of the data that actually makes it a question. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

Just drag this files again in XCode or add reference of those files by clicking on `+` button on bottom left corner of XCode and then click on 'Add files'.

Answer (score 1):

Import these red colored classes from another folder or backup folder to your current project.

To sort this issue permanently open your project folder and move these classes to main project folder.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this red colour issue by re-adding those class files and i deleted these red colour classes. I Think it's because of the path issue.Solved by readding.